Distance of a point from plane along given direction
Given a point $(1,-2,3)$ and a plane $x-y+z=5,$ I am asked to find the distance measured parallel to the line $x/2 = y/3 = -z/6.$
I first found the distance of the point from the plane, then considered the vector $\vec d$ connecting the point and the plane, perpendicular to the plane: $\vec d = t<1,-1,1>.$ Knowing the magnitude of $\vec d,$ we can caluclate the value of the parameter $t.$ Following this, I simply obtained the dot product of $\vec d$ along the direction cosine of the given line.
With this method, I am obtaining the answer $1/3,$ however the correct answer is $1.$ What is the mistake in my approach?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Instead of the perpendicular, take the direction $x/2 = y/3 = z/(-6)$.

Yours is not the most efficient way, but I think I found where you made the error. You calculated $d$, and found $$|d|=\frac1{\sqrt 3}$$
Notice immediately that this value is greater than your answer, which should give you a clue that you did something wrong, since the perpendicular distance to the plane is shortest. Then you calculated the cosine of the angle between $(1,-1,1)$ and $(2,3,-6)$ and multiplied with $|d|$. Instead, you should have divided. Why is that? Because you want to know the hypotenuse in a right angle triangle, when you know the angle and the side.
The picture below is not to scale. You are given point $B$ your $d$ is $AB$, and you calculated the angle $ABD$. You need to get $BC$, but instead you calculated $BD$.




Given a point $(1,-2,3)$ and a plane $x-y+z=5,$ I am asked to find the distance measured parallel to the line $x/2 = y/3 = -z/6.$

I simply obtained the dot product of the vector $\vec d$ along the direction cosine of the given line.

Your mistake is in this final step, as nicely illustrated by Andrei.
One correct solution method is to first find the intersection of the given plane and the line through the given point and parallel to the given line—that is, the line $\vec r=\begin{pmatrix}1 \\-2 \\3\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}2 \\3 \\-6\end{pmatrix}$—then just compute the the distance between this intersection point and the given point. We indeed obtain $1$, as required.
